# Using loop to insert array type of data in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops

I'd like to insert array data `equip` to a table using loop.

```
var svr = 1;
var equip = [3, 4, 5];
```

For that I need to insert the data three times.

Looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO khnp.link_server_equipment_map(svr, equip)
VALUES (1, 3);

INSERT INTO khnp.link_server_equipment_map(svr, equip)
VALUES (1, 4);

INSERT INTO khnp.link_server_equipment_map(svr, equip)
VALUES (1, 5);
```

Can someone please get me out of this rabbit hole? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try unnest:

```
INSERT INTO khnp.link_server_equipment_map(svr, equip) 
VALUES (1,  UNNEST(ARRAY[3, 4, 5]));`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INSERT` statement to insert several rows.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

According to your mentioned data example the rows insertion would be done this way

```
   INSERT INTO khnp.link_server_equipment_map(svr, equip) VALUES
     (1, 3),
     (1, 4),
     (1, 5);
```

Also to avoid adding the array content one by one you can use the `UNNEST` [array function.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html)